# How can I block default project creation and force standard projects when using AppScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I am seeing hundreds of violations in Security Command Center pointing to the default AppScript service account having owner role. I am looking to block the default project creation and force end users to request a standard project where we have greater control over access.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the default AppScript service account being owner is [default behavior](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#default_cloud_platform_projects).

Now once the "default" project is created, you can move it to a regular project this [way](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I remember reading that. However, I am looking for a way to block the default project creation and require a standard project. Is this something that can be defined ahead of time? Is there a choice up front to select a project or take the default one?

Comment: Is that the [violation](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/concepts-vulnerabilities-findings#iam-findings) in question? If it is then it is throwing a false positive as the default appscript service account is not a user created service account. so IMO opinion should be excluded from the scan.

Comment: Possibly a feature request: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers